# Show in twig the result of a JOIN query in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, join, twig, dql

I have 2 tables which are not related by `ORM` so I do the`JOIN` as follows:

```
$dql="SELECT u, o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN BackendBundle:Users u
      WITH o.userid=u.id";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```

When I send the query to twig to show it on the screen it shows me an error.

This is the code in `twig`:

```
{% for ordenes in pagination %}
  <td>{{ ordenes.orderid }}</td>
  <td>{{ ordenes.orderdate|date("Y-m-d") }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

And the error is this:

> Neither the property "orderid" nor one of the methods "orderid()",
>   "getorderid()"/"isorderid()" or "__call()" exist and have public
>   access in class "BackendBundle\Entity\Users"

If I run `twig` this code:

```
{{dump(pagination)}}
```

It correctly shows me what the query returns:

```
  #currentPageNumber: 3
  #numItemsPerPage: 20
  #items: array:40 [▼
    0 => Orders {#522 ▼
      -orderid: 158
      -orderdate: DateTime {#476 ▶}
      -ordernumber: "FFFFFFFFFFF"
      -customername: "UUUUUUUUUUUU"
      -customeraddress: "OOOOOO"
      -countrycode: "US"
      -shippingaddress: "PPPPPP"
      -status: "Ordered"
      -subtotal: "5.00"
      -shippingcost: "2.82"
      -tax: "0.00"
      -discount: "0.00"
      -totalorder: "7.82"
      -shippingcarrier: "Fedex"
      -userid: "1206"
    }
    1 => Users {#525 ▼
      -id: 1206
      -username: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
      -yourname: null
      -firstname: "GGGG"
      -lastname: "IIIIII"
      -middlename: ""
      -address: "oooooooooo"
      -address2: ""
      -apartment: ""
      -pobox: ""
      -city: "Monsey"
      -state: "NY"
      -zipcode: "88888888"
      -country: "USA"
      -countrycode: "US"
      -email: "xxxxxxxxxxx@hotmail.com"
      -datein: DateTime {#521 ▶}
    }
```

My question is how can I show this result in twig ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? You currently build a list of orders and users, iterating over that and outputting orders will fail as you see now when the loop hits the first user entity. If this is intended, and you want to list out orders and users in the same table, then you need to check which entity the current pagination item (ordenes) is before deciding what entity fields to output. I highly expect you aren't trying to build a jumbled list of orders and users though, but it's not easy to recommend something when you haven't said what result you expect

Comment: Maybe you meant: `{{ for ordenes in pagination.items }}`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. JimL - I want to be able to display a table with the information of the orders that the user made.

Comment: Do you have a spesific user you want the orders for or do you want to list every user and their orders?

Comment: I want to list all the orders for example: ordenid (this in the table order), email (it is in the users table), etc.

Comment: Ok, so you want to list all orders from all users? You could do this with a select partial, but I'd strongly suggest adding the relation to the ORM. That way you can just select the orders you want, join in the user relation and be done with it

Comment: That I understand if I already do the relationship with the ORM always works as always. Think about how this works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing and trying to solve this problem. Finally create the relationship in the files and between the 2 tables in this way:

```
//BackendBundle\Entity\Orders:
indexes:
    fk_order_user1_idx:
        columns:
            - user_id
......
manyToOne:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        cascade: {  }
        fetch: LAZY
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: null
        joinColumns:
            user_id:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

Also in the Entity:

```
//Orders.php
/**
 * @var \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
private $user;
......
/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param \BackendBundle\Entity\Users $user
 *
 * @return Users
 */
public function setUser(\BackendBundle\Entity\Users $user = null)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return \BackendBundle\Entity\Users
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

I updated the database:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And I make the query in this way:

```
$dql="SELECT u, o
      FROM BackendBundle:Orders o
      JOIN o.user u";
$query=$em->createQuery($dql);
```